# Why Google API (Directory List) keeps returning 403? Are there evolutions? New Versions? GPDR / LGPD issues?

Tags: javascript, google-api-client, google-admin-sdk

I have an application that suddenly stop to work due to the users list (https://content.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?orderBy=email&viewType=domain_public&maxResults=200&customer=my_customer&domain=XXX&key=XXX) keeps returning:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This application is provided to 2 distinct domains. It works properly to one but not to other. Same code... just appId, apiKey and clientId changes. I configured wide domain delegation with scopes (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user), also configured API KEY, OAuth 2.0 Client.

I tried to recreate the whole project, all credentials, tried http and https... same error.

Is there something that changed in the API specification? Something that am I missing?

**EDITED - Source code requested:**

*I just copied this whole code, changed "settings" with credentials and executed in a browser console. The code works before or after authentication, but with the 403 response :-(*

```js
// This first part I got from https://github.com/lord22shark/google

(function (__window) {

    const Google = function (configuration, __callback) {

        if ((!configuration) || !(configuration instanceof Object)) {

            throw new Error('Google API Wrapper - "configuration" must be defined!');

        }

        if ((!configuration.apiKey) || !(typeof(configuration.apiKey) === 'string') || (configuration.apiKey === '')) {

            throw new Error('Google API Wrapper - "apiKey" must be defined!');

        }

        if ((!configuration.discoveryDocs) || !(configuration.discoveryDocs instanceof Array) || (configuration.discoveryDocs.length === 0)) {

            throw new Error('Google API Wrapper - "discoveryDocs" must be a defined array!');

        }

        if ((!configuration.clientId) || !(typeof(configuration.clientId) === 'string') || (configuration.clientId === '')) {

            throw new Error('Google API Wrapper - "clientId" must be defined!');

        }

        if ((!configuration.scope) || !(typeof(configuration.scope) === 'string') || (configuration.scope === '')) {

            throw new Error('Google API Wrapper - "scope" must be defined!');

        }

        const thiz = this;

        /**
         *
         */
        this.element = document.createElement('script');

        this.element.type = 'text/javascript';
        this.element.async = true;
        this.element.defer = true;
        this.element.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/api.js';

        /**
         *
         */
        this.element.onload = function () {

            gapi.load('client:auth2', function () {

                gapi.client.init({
                    'apiKey': configuration.apiKey,
                    'discoveryDocs': configuration.discoveryDocs,
                    'clientId': configuration.clientId,
                    'scope': configuration.scope
                }).then(function () {

                    thiz.googleAuthInstance = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();

                    // Listen for sign-in state changes.
                    // The callback function must be a global named function
                    thiz.googleAuthInstance.isSignedIn.listen(onUpdateGoogleSignInStatus);

                    thiz.setSigninStatus();

                }).catch(function (error) {

                    __callback(error);

                });

            }.bind(thiz));

        };

        /**
         *
         */
        this.element.onreadystatechange = function () {

            if (this.readyState === 'complete') {

                this.onload();

            }

        };

        /**
         *
         */
        this.setSigninStatus = function (isSignedIn) {

            if ((isSignedIn === true) || (isSignedIn === undefined)) {

                this.user = this.googleAuthInstance.currentUser.get();

                this.authorized = this.user.hasGrantedScopes(configuration.scope);

                this.authorizationToken = (this.authorized) ? this.user.getAuthResponse().access_token : null;

                if (!this.authorized) {

                    this.googleAuthInstance.signIn().then(function (authenticatedUser) {

                        __callback(this.user, this.authorized, this.authorizationToken, this.googleAuthInstance);

                    }.bind(this)).catch(function (error) {

                        __callback(error);

                    });

                } else {

                    __callback(this.user, this.authorized, this.authorizationToken, this.googleAuthInstance);

                }

            }

        };

        /**
         *
         */
        this.getAuthInstance = function () {

            return this.googleAuthInstance || null;

        };

        /**
         *
         */
        this.getUser = function () {

            return this.user || null;

        };

        /**
         *
         */
        this.getAuthorizationToken = function () {

            return this.authorizationToken;

        };

        /**
         *
         */
        this.getConfiguration = function () {

            return configuration;

        };

        /**
         *
         */
        this.hasGrantedScopes = function () {

            return this.authorized;

        };

        /**
         *
         */
        this.disconnect = function (deAuthenticate, callback) {

            if (this.googleAuthInstance.isSignedIn.get()) {

                if (deAuthenticate === true) {

                    this.googleAuthInstance.disconnect().then(function () {

                        if ((callback) && (callback instanceof Function)) {

                            callback(true);

                        }

                    });

                } else {

                    this.googleAuthInstance.signOut().then(function () {

                        if ((callback) && (callback instanceof Function)) {

                            callback(false);

                        }

                    });

                }

            }

        };

        /**
         *
         */
         __window.onUpdateGoogleSignInStatus = function onUpdateGoogleSignInStatus (isSignedIn) {

            this.setSigninStatus(isSignedIn);

        }.bind(this);

        document.body.appendChild(this.element);

    };

    __window.Google = Google;

})(window);

// This second part is part of my project - Settings

var settings = {
    appId: 'xxx',
    apiKey: 'xxx',
    discoveryDocs: [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/admin/directory_v1/rest'
    ],
    clientId: 'xxx',
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly profile email'
};

var domains = [
    'mydomain1.com', 'mydomain2.com'    
];

// This is a bootstrap that I make some requests to sync information retrieved from oauth2 and my application, where I make the API call after authorized

function bootstrap (google) {

    if (google instanceof Error) {

        console.log(google);

    } else {

        // Here I Start Angular angular.element(document).ready.... get the user domain...

        var userDomain = 'mydomain1';

        var profile = google.getUser().getBasicProfile();

        console.log(profile);

        gapi.client.directory.users.list({
            'viewType': 'domain_public',
            'customer': 'my_customer',
            'maxResults': 200,
            'orderBy': 'email',
            'domain': userDomain
        }).then(function (response) {

            console.log(response.result.users);

        }).catch(function (error) {

            console.log(error);

        });

    }

}

// Invokes Google with settings and if the authenticated user is part of one of my domains, I call "bootstrap" function

var google = new Google(settings, function (user, authorized, authorizationToken, authInstance) {

    if (authorized !== undefined && authorizationToken !== undefined) {

        var email = user.getBasicProfile().getEmail();

        var allowed = domains.reduce(function (previous, current) {

            if (email.indexOf(current) !== -1) {

                previous += 1;

            }

            return previous;

        }, 0);

        if (allowed === 0) {

            authInstance.disconnect();

            bootstrap(new Error('User does not belong to XXX domain.'));

        } else {

            bootstrap(google);

        }

    } else {

        bootstrap(new Error(user.details));

    }

});
```

Comment: Are these two subdomains of the same account or two completely different domains? In which domain have you created your service account with domain wide delegation?

Comment: Hi Mateo. Thanks for your reply. They are completely different. 2 distinct G Suite accounts. I created domain wide delegation in both domains. The domain that's not working is a G Suite Bussiness account... the one that's working is a G Suite Basic account

Comment: Forgot to say that even in API Explorer (Try this API) I get the same error.

Comment: Hi ! When running ```Try this API``` are you using the **admin** G Suite business account to execute this API call? Also, are you setting the appropiate ```customer``` parameter in the API call ? For a quick check you can set in ```Try this API``` the ```customer``` parameter to ```my_customer``` and see if you get any errors on that call. [Here is a link](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list?apix_params=%7B%22customer%22%3A%22my_customer%22%7D#try-it) to that documentation. :D

Comment: Hi Mateo! I tried with 2 accounts. One "normal" and the admin account. Tried "my_customer"still getting the same error. 403, forbidden. :-(

Comment: Hi ! Could you please provide me a sample code with no sensitive information or some reproduction steps (detailing what you did and set in this project) so that I can try to reproduce your behaviour as accurately as possible? Many thanks !

Comment: Ok! Sure! I just have some tasks to finish... and ASAP I'll provide the code! Thanks

Comment: Question edited! Source provided! Thanks again, Mateo.

Comment: Hi ! So your two accounts are a Business Starter (the one working) and a Business Stadndard account (the one not working) right? Check [here](https://workspace.google.com/pricing.html) which ones are you using and let me know which one it is. Thanks ! :D

Comment: Exactly! The one not working is Business Standard.

Comment: Could you try running this API call with your super admin account on both Standard and Starter accounts? Some errors might be due to certain admin permissions not granted, so by testing this behaviour with your **super admin** accounts will tell us if that was the issue :D

Comment: I have another projects in this domain (one not working) and I tried with with a service account... Works perfectly. The viewType parameter in the script os **admin_view**. So instead of using **domain_public** I tried **admin_view** with the script I posted in question. It worked for a super admin account but not for a normal account. Is this related to domain delegation or inpersonate?

Comment: So it works correctly when you use a super admin account right?

Comment: Sure, Works correctly with the "one not working" domain and viewType **admin_view**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to run [users.list()](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list) you should be an administrator with the right permissions as there are different type of Google Workspace admins. That is why you can run successfully your code when you run it from a super admin account and why if you set `viewType` to `admin_view` you can run it successfully too.

However, while user accounts can only be modified by administrators, any user on the domain can read user profiles (in your case this would be possible as your method is for listing them). According to the [documentation detailing this](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#retrieve_users_non_admin) in order to do this setting `viewType` to `domain_public` you **must first enable [contact sharing](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60218)** for the domain (individual users with contact sharing disable will not be retrieved). Also note that the following scope should be enough `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly`.

Comment: Hi Mateo! Thanks for your reply. Enabling contact sharing did work... but not for all users.  In my understanding, each user has to consent their data to be accessed by "public" requests. I believe that Google changed the approach concerning GRPD (LGPD in Brazil) requests, so this caused the sudden interruption. Thanks again!